# Graphical HTTP client for windows

Tags: windows, http, rest, client

I am looking for a Windows graphical utility for performing HTTP operations.

For example, I want to be able to say things like:

POST to http://example.org/test/service
With a POST body: "Data goes here"

Does anyone know a good piece of software for doing this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087185/http-testing-tool-easily-send-post-get-put

Answer (score 87):

I too have been frustrated by the lack of good graphical http clients available for Windows. So over the past couple years I've been developing one myself: [I'm Only Resting](https://web.archive.org/web/20180329110429/http://www.swensensoftware.com:80/im-only-resting), "a feature-rich WinForms-based HTTP client." It's open source (Apache License, Version 2.0) with freely available downloads.

It currently has fairly complete coverage of HTTP features except for file uploads, and it provides a very good user interface with great request and response management.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Well done, this works well!

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I wrote a REST client plugin called Requester for Sublime Text, https://github.com/kylebebak/Requester. It's inspired by HTTPie and Postman. It's very powerful and easy to use, and it's cross-platform. If you're not in love with your HTTP client it's definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 46):

**Update: For people that still come across this, Postman is your best bet now: https://www.getpostman.com/apps**

---

RestClient is my favorite.  It's Java based.  I think it should meet your needs quite nicely.  I particularly like the Auth suppport.

https://github.com/wiztools/rest-client

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Wanted to follow up here much later and say, [hurl.it](http://hurl.it) is now another great web based alternative, regardless of OS.

Comment: It should be noted this is a Java tool. So you now have two things to install.

Comment: @QueueHammer Unless you are java developer

Comment: Postman or Insomnia: https://insomnia.rest/

Answer (score 32):

Have you looked at Fiddler 2 from Microsoft?

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Allows you to generate most types of request for testing, including POST.  It also supports capturing HTTP requests made by other applications and reusing those for testing.

Comment: Fiddler isn't a Microsoft tool...

Comment: Help -> About Fiddler -> Author: Eric Lawrence (ericlaw@microsoft.com) Copyright 2003-2010 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Just because its not on Microsoft.com doesn't mean its not a Microsoft tool.

Comment: Just because it's made by someone who works at Microsoft does not make it a Microsoft tool. . . 

Reflector is another example of a tool made by a Microsoft employee. He even went on to sell it to another company (Red-Gate).

Comment: It IS a Microsoft tool according to the license agreement. http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/license.asp

Comment: @rifferte - aside from ssgs point above, why is the Microsoft copyright notice in the about window then?  Its a Microsoft tool.

Comment: @rifferte The difference is that Lutz wrote reflector before he went to work for Microsoft.

Comment: OK - I stand correct :)

Odd that the copyright on the site is his, yet the one on the tool is MS. . .

Comment: And now it is purchased by Telerik, and Eric Lawrence is becoming a Telerik employee.

Comment: I have decided to end this debate by editing the "from Microsoft" out of the answer above.

Comment: I'd thank you to leave my post alone - it was fully correct when it was posted. The "debate" ended nearly two full years before you made your edit.

Comment: anyone konws why I downloaded baidu browser rather than fiddler via this link? both using IE or Firefox...

Comment: Fiddler is now owned and developed by Teleric.

Comment: @aaron I suspect it is because you are in China.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Microsoft's [WFetch tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284285) also. This is a good tool for all HTTP operations.

Answer (score 4):

You could try Jsonium tool [http://jsonium.org](http://jsonium.org/)- nice free tool specialized on requests with JSON in bodies and responses

Comment: The website is currently down

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=B134A806-D50E-4664-8348-DA5C17129210&displaylang=en

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9780/

http://soft-net.net/SendHTTPTool.aspx

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, for simplistic stuff like that I typically whip up a quick HTML form in a local file and load that up in a browser.

Comment: So Simple! I'm POSTing some base64encoded files to web service. They are long strings. I've managed to crash/lockup most of the GUI clients when pasting in the long strings.By doing as you suggested, this was the best and easiest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I like [rest-client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) a lot for the purposes you described. It's a Java application to test REST-based web services.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is still interest Eclipse Labs [Rest Client tool](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/restclient-tool/) is an excellent choice. I'm trying it in Windows in an EXE version and works smoothly.

I've worked also with [Rest Client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) previously and its great too.

Answer (score 1):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snmba.restclient

works from Android Tablets & Phones.  Flexible enough to try various combinations.