# Escaping curl command in Windows

Tags: windows, curl, marklogic

I'm trying to run a `curl` command from the command line in Windows, but for the life of me I can't figure out how I'm supposed to escape it.

I'm executing this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl --anyauth --user user:password -X POST -d "{\"rest-api\":{\"name\":\"BizSimDebug3\"}}" -H "Content-type: application/xml" http://localhost:8002/v1/rest-apis
```

And I'm getting this:

```
<rapi:error xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
  <rapi:status-code>400</rapi:status-code>
  <rapi:status>Bad Request</rapi:status>
  <rapi:message-code>RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT</rapi:message-code>
  <rapi:message>Your bootstrap payload caused the server to throw an error.  Underlying error message: XDMP-DOCROOTTEXT: xdmp:get-request-body() -- Invalid root text "{&amp;quot;rest-api&amp;quot;:{&amp;quot;name&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;BizSimDebug3&amp;quot;}}" at  line 1</rapi:message>
</rapi:error>
```

Is there something else I need to do to escape the inner quotes in the -d flag?  Or am I overlooking the real issue entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XDMP-DOCROOTTEXT` error indicates the server is trying to parse the payload as `XML` and failing.

The `Content-Type` header is telling the server that you're sending `XML`, but the payload is `JSON`.

Try changing the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`

Comment: *headdesk*  Ayup.  I suspected I might be doing something stupid.  This was indeed the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

This works in Windows:

```
 
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"Field1\": 123, \"Field2\": 456 }" "http://localhost:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting is hell.   By "Windows Command Line and your prompt I presume you mean cmd.com ?.  That doest quote the same as linux shells.

For this simplistic experiment I recommend going for 2 kinds of quotes to avoid escaping But even then its unlikely to work

```
curl --anyauth --user user:password -X POST -d "{'rest-api':{'name':'BizSimDebug3'}}" -H "Content-type: application/xml" http://localhost:8002/v1/rest-apis
```

Better luck might be had by going with a unix-like shell such as running cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/)  or maybe xmlsh (www.xmlsh.org) which escape like linux does.

You really are going to have a nightmare running anything complex through the windows command line natively.

-David

Comment: Thanks, David.  I'm running cmd.exe.  The outer-double inner-single approach didn't work.  I'm trying to avoid doing this with Cygwin and keep this simple if possible, but I'm running out of patience.  The really irritating part is I know full well I figured out how to do this once, but I can't recall HOW....

Comment: Maybe try things mentioned here Maybe try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835039/graphical-http-client-for-windows