# not able to pass data in url through command prompt in curl

Tags: curl

Can anyone give any suggestion why this error is occurring ?

**cmd curl command**

```
curl https://xyz.com/Dash.aspx?nl=Gas%20Daily&nl2=Home
```

**Error**

> nl2 is not recognized as an an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I have also tried

```
curl https://xyz.com/Dash.aspx?nl=Gas%20Daily'&'nl2=Home
```

But still the same error

Comment: You're encountering some kind of shell escaping issue. Given that curl is multi-platform, please indicate which OS/shell you're actually working with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping curl command in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966989/escaping-curl-command-in-windows)

Comment: @PaulSweatte I don't think this is a duplicate, as that other question (despite the title) turned out to be a problem with setting the correct request header, not an escaping problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's an escaping issue. Try enclosing the URL in  quotes, like so:

```
curl 'https://xyz.com/Dash.aspx?nl=Gas%20Daily&nl2=Home'
```