# JSONDecodeError Django

Tags: python, django

I have an API that is sending me a **POST request (JSON)** for testing. I was doing a lot with the JSON, but all of a sudden it stopped working and giving me a `JSONDecodeError`. I tried all sorts of things, like using `request.POST` but nothing worked correctly like I said this was working at one point. Any assistance is appreciated.

Test that gives the error:
In the Windows Command prompt, running:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/webhook/webhook_receiver/ -d '{"foo": "bar"}'
```

> Error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

View:

```
def webhook_receiver(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the incoming JSON Data
        data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        received_json_data = json.loads(data)
        return HttpResponse(received_json_data)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("not Post")
```

Comment: Is everything running? What data is being sent?

Comment: @Zev curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/webhook/webhook_receiver/ -d '{"foo": "bar"}' is what I was trying

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is the combination of your command quoting syntax and the Windows terminal interpreter (what you posted would have been fine using Bash for example).

See [Escaping curl command in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966989/escaping-curl-command-in-windows) for details.

---

The actual error (which you really ought to have posted) looks like this:

> ```
> Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /webhook/webhook_receiver/
> Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
> ```

That says the data you are passing into the decoder does not start with a valid character (such as a "{" if the JSON is supposed to be a dict, or "[" for an array). You can probably work out what the problem is really easily by adding a print() for the start of the data, e.g. like:

```
print('first few characters=<{}>'.format(data[:4]))
```

Comment: I was trying curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000 -d '{"Foo":"bar"}' is that not correct?

Comment: It looks OK, but there is no substitute for looking at what the Python code is actually getting. After all, you are getting an error!

Comment: I am not sure where to use this print statement. Do I put it in my views?

Comment: Yes, and you'll see the result in the terminal where you ran the server. I just tested your code and it worked for me (I didn't get an error) so the issue may be in something you haven't put in the question yet.

Comment: Ok, I get `first few characters=<'{fo>` which is valid is it not? Seems like maybe the double quotes are being stripped?

Comment: @Zev I tested it in a brand new project, app, venv and all, still same problem.

Comment: What terminal are you using to run curl?

Comment: Yes, you need to replace it with encoded quotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612248/how-to-escape-single-quotes-into-double-quotes-into-single-quotes/18612754#18612754

Comment: You may also want to try `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/fire/webhook_receiver/ -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"foo": "bar"}'` but I'm not on windows so I can't test it.

Comment: The culprit is the combination of your command quoting syntax and the Windows terminal interpreter (what you posted would have been fine using Bash for example) as per @zev. You don't need the content-type header as its presence merely tells the receiver how to interpret the body data...and at least in your closed world example, you already know it to be JSON.